# Apache.Httpd+Php or Apache.Tomcat+Java for large project

Tags: java, php, apache

I want to start some large project. There are two technologies that i can use for it:
1. Apache.Httpd+Php
2. Apache.Tomcat+Java

RDBMS is MySQL

I need to select technology and argue the choice
Thanks for advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large projects can be done in php or java. I tend towards java and tomcat because the language is cleaner and in my opinion more robust and secure. On the other hand java is harder to learn and sometimes makes things more complicated than with php. Usually you also need some third party tools/frameworks for webapplications.

With a good understaning of php you can also build clean, robust and secure projects. The other way around, with java and tomcat you can also build lousy implemented applications.

In the end it depends on the resources you have. If you have skilled php programmers, php is the solution, if you have java programmers, java is the solution.

If you have no experienced programmers php is probably easier to start but the tendency to get a project with bugs and a bad design is bigger than if you use java.

In the end, know how usually is much more important than technology.